# invalid procedure/call argument while collecting blank control values in collection?

Tags: excel, vba

adding control name values in a collection whenever theyre left blank on a userform when a user wants to submit the data.

it loops through all sheets and adds all values to the collection, but it gets past the last control on the last page (6) and throws me an invalid procedure/call argument error on this line :

`For Each icontrol In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls`

rest of code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim icontrol As Control
    Dim colBlankFields As New Collection
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
        For Each icontrol In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
            If icontrol.Visible = True Then
                Select Case True
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "opt*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "cmb*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                End Select
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    If IsEmpty(colBlankFields) Then
    Else
        MsgBox colBlankFields
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index starts at zero, therefore is not equal to the page count. The index for page 5 is 4.

So, either loop -1:

```
For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count -1 
    ' ...
Next
```

or use a `For Each`:

```
Dim page As Page 'Not sure about the the datatype

For Each page In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
    ' ...
Next
```